# Sun distance, temperature changes

Tags: temperature, solar-system, weather

During winter,  given that over a few days the earth is basically the same distance from the sun,  why can there be such a significant drop in temperature in just one or two days that have equally clear skies?
What are the other variables (cold air wind?) and what causes them on some days but not others?

Comment: Over the whole year the Earth is basically the same distance from the Sun, about 150 million km. The difference between closest and farthest distance is only 5 million km. That is less than 2% deviation around the average.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Last I checked, weather questions are still on topic here. That said, if no satisfying answers arise in the next day or two, you may want to see about migrating over to EarthScience.SE

Comment: It is a "Weather" tag, used by this site,  gerbil.   Please remove the down vote,  or I'll visit your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is that barometric air pressure differences cause wind-driven movement of cold and warm air masses over the land. Where I live, we can see a 40 degree F temperature drop overnight if a high-pressure zone parks itself over idaho and western montana and blows icy cold air westward into oregon; then the temperature bounces back when marine air from off the pacific coast blows inland and pushes back on that other air mass.